# How to restrict multiple forms sending the same text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Windows 10, Google Forms, LVL: ROOKIE

I want to restrict multiple forms by multiple people sending me the same link.
For example: 
I'm in a group with 10 other people, and we all want to submit a link to our favorite restaurant through the form, which will be sent to our sheet. But I don't want more than 1 link from the same website. So when someone is writing on a form, it says "That link has already been submitted" and then they have to find a new link of their NEXT favorite.

Is this possible in google scripts or forms?

Comment: How do you get the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving feedback to the user as they write onto Google form is not possible. Google form is not dynamic. Even the other form service such as Typeform, SurveyMonkey, or Form360 nothing has this facility. These forms have only one purpose, that is to capture the data.

If you need the form to be dynamic, like in your case, as the user type onto the form, it needs to look into the Database to see whether there is any matching entry or not. Then respond to the user based on the output of the query, to do that you need to build a custom HTML form using Google Apps HTML service.

A possible way with Google Form will be to run a script after a user submits the form which will compare the new response by the user with the existing data in the database and then send a response back via email based on the outcome of the search. Send an email saying the restaurant that you added is already in the database, else send that your response has been accepted.

Another possible way will be to show the list of restaurants that is already in the database to the user so that the user can submit a different set of data.